# I want to change the value of the state with the next values from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change the value of the state with the next value of `eyes` everytime when I click to be the next one

```
import React from "react";

import "./App.css";

function avatar() {
  let eyes = ["close", "happy", "drizzy"];

  const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState({ eyeType: "default" });

  function nextEyes(){
      // do something here
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="avatarEyes" onClick={nextEyes}>{avatar.eyeType}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default avatar;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```js
import React from "react";

import "./App.css";

function avatar() {
  let eyes = ["close", "happy", "drizzy"];

  const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState({ eyeType: "default" });

  let eyesIndex = eyes.indexOf(avatar.eyeType);

  function nextEyes() {
    eyesIndex += 1;
    if (eyesIndex >= eyes.length) { eyesIndex = 0; }
    avatar.eyeType = eyes[eyesIndex];
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="avatarEyes" onClick={nextEyes}>{avatar.eyeType}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default avatar;
```